# How to write a psp in k8s only for a specific user?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, k8s-serviceaccount

```
minikube start
--extra-config=apiserver.enable-admission-plugins=PodSecurityPolicy
--addons=pod-security-policy
```

we have a default namespace in which the nginx service account does not have the rights to launch the nginx container

when creating a pod, use the command

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx -n default --as system:serviceaccount:default:nginx-sa
```

as a result, we get an error

```
 Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root (pod: "nginx_default(49e939b0-d238-4e04-a122-43f4cfabea22)", container: nginx)
```

as I understand it, it is necessary to write a psp policy that will allow the nginx-sa service account to run under, but I do not understand how to write it correctly for a specific service account

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nginx-sa
  namespace: default

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-sa-role
  namespace: default
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps",""]
    resources: [ "deployments","pods" ]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-sa-role-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: nginx-sa
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: nginx-sa-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: Have you looked at this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64551602/forbidden-systemserviceaccountdefaultdefault-cannot-create-resource-how-t ?

Comment: unfortunately, it does not fit

Comment: Can you get the UID of that service account using ```kubectl get serviceaccounts/nginx-sa -o yaml``` ?

Comment: uid: a30d2e76-f0e6-4715-9cc5-00f787972a3b

Comment: PodSecurityPolicy has been deprecated. Instead, you should create a Security Context containig runasuser, as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: unfortunately, this is not possible, the task is to write a psp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...but I do not understand how to write it correctly for a specific service account`

After you get your special psp ready for your nginx, you can grant your nginx-sa to use the special psp like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: role-to-use-special-psp
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resourceNames:
  - special-psp-for-nginx
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  verbs:
  - use
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: bind-to-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: role-to-use-special-psp
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: nginx-sa
  namespace: default
```